# Invalid procedure call or argument applying Excel conditional formatting from Access vba

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, conditional-formatting

I have read numerous examples where this code works; however, when I try to execute it, it isn't working and I don't see why.

```
Dim xl As Object
Set xl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
xl.Range("G2:G375").FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=OR(G2=""New"",G2=""Reintroduced"")"
```

I get a `Run-time error '5': Invalid procedure call or argument`. Have tried it by defining activesheet, worksheet name, active workbook, etc. and still get this same error. Everything I have read says it should work, but again, it isn't.

Also, there is data in the spreadsheet that is opened else where in the code.

Here is just one example of what I am using as a reference:

[enter link description here](http://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/28248381/Conditional-Formatting-for-Excel-from-Access-VBA.html)

Comment: Add `Option Explicit` to the Declarations section of the module which contains that code.  Then run Debug->Compile from the VB Editor's main menu.  Fix anything the compiler complains about (`xlExpression`?), then try compile again.  Keep at it until no more compile errors.  If you encounter a compile error you don't know how to fix, tell us the compile error message and what is highlighted when the compiler complains.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may need to add a reference to the Microsoft Excel Object Library in Access.

With that reference, this code worked when I tested it.

```
Dim xl As Excel.Application
Set xl = New Excel.Application
xl.Workbooks.Add
xl.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("G2:G375").FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=OR(G2=""New"",G2=""Reintroduced"")"
xl.Visible = True
```

Comment: If you're going to reference the Excel library, might as well early-bind the `xl` instance and benefit from IntelliSense/autocomplete.

Comment: Man, I thought I already had it selected so I didn't bother checking. Turns out I didn't have it selected... thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem recently with formulas when I was working on another laptop. Found out the the formula was wrong, as excel was set up for "," and the formula contained ";" as a separator. Classic.